# Getting and rendering images

Tags: javascript, react-native, image

I would like to preface this by saying I am not a front-end dev. this was dropped on my plate and I'm struggling getting through it.

My current solution is to fetch a list of the images (nfts, yes. I know.) from our API, which contains links to the nft's respective CDN hosting their off-chain metadata. (most of them are in [this](https://testlaunchmynft.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmQz7HchJiJwb31VxR2mvaPkHgxjBGNuw4Wpd74WqcNq9J/690.json) format) the images sometimes appear in my SafeAreaView object, but sometimes only on the right or left half, or they don't render at all, and if they do, they promptly disappear. I believe the issue with some images not rendering is that the second call to the CDN is too slow, but i'm not sure how to solve this.

My ideal solutions are:

- have a loading spinner until all items are loaded
- force loading in order of the list

Here is my current code:

```js
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import SelectedWalletContext from '../../../theme/SelectedWalletContext';
import { View, Image, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

export default function FetchNFT({  modalRef, onPress }) {
    const { selectedWallet } = useContext(SelectedWalletContext);
    const [nfts, setNFTs] = useState([]);
    const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    const imageWidth = screenWidth * 0.43;
    const imageHeight = imageWidth; 

    const handleOnNFTClick = (nft, nftData) => { // Will be implemented once rendering is fixed
        onPress(nft, nftData);
        modalRef.current.present();
    };

    const solNfts = () => {
        let data = []
        axios.get(`https://rpc.unisonwallet.xyz/rpc/v1/sol/nfts/Fpa2S13a82aBu9YGscAEqttXJaCZb5TVzhscmUApnzhP/mb`, {timeout: 100000}).then(res => {
            if (res.data.code === 1 && res.data.data.length > 0) {
                res.data.data.forEach(token => axios.get(token.metadata.nftMetadataJson.uri).then(res1 => data.push({image: res1.data.image, name: res1.data.name})))
            }
        }).catch(err => console.error("Fetch error " + err));
        setNFTs(data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        switch (selectedWallet.name) { // Add more chains
            case 'sol': solNfts(); break;
            default: setNFTs([]);
        }
    }, [selectedWallet.name]);
    
    return (
        <View>
        <SafeAreaView style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
            {selectedWallet.name === 'sol' && nfts.map((nft, index) => (
                <TouchableOpacity key={index}>
                    <Image source={{uri: nft.image}} style={{width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight, borderRadius:10}} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
        </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
    )
}
```

I tried the above code, and got occasional loading, but never saw the same NFTs, or in the same order. There was also a bizarre issue where tokens would only load on the right or left side, with no rhyme or reason.